# Getting text color in appium

Tags: ruby, appium

Is there any method to get text color in appium (lets say android apps). And also I want to assert that the text color is red/blue/green in color.
I use ruby to write the scripts.

Answer (score 4):

There is **no way to get text color in Appium** for native iOS/Android apps, simply because UIAutomator2/XCUITest do not expose this type of data.

Appium is not a tool for visual testing, but is for functional testing.